# Is DNS service provider allowed to make changes to my domain without my request?

Tags: dns

Let's say that I own an `example.com` domain and my domain name registrar provides me the DNS service and also the hosting service(IPv4 address for my web-server is 192.0.2.35). For example they have an A record `www    IN    A    192.0.2.35` in the `example.com.` zone in their DNS server and `35    IN    PTR    www.example.com.` in `2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.` zone.
Am I correct that any changes to `example.com.` zone or entry for 192.0.2.35 in `2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.` zone should be done only based on my requests? Any changes made by my DNS provider not based on my requests are basically a security breach?

Comment: This should not happen unless you have not paid the bill. ;-) What did it change to? What does the company say for it's self?

Comment: Thanks for reply! They said that this was a human error. As I am new to this I simply wanted to make sure that if I have understood the responsibility boundaries and this overall DNS service correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking the DNS provider is allowed to change your zone file whenever they want as you don't own the zone file you are licensing services from the provider. Having said that most providers wont arbitrarily make changes to your zone file without your permission unless you have not paid the bill or they have been directed to by court order as it is not a good business strategy to alienate your customers and make them want to leave your services behind.

In your comments you mention that the provider identified this as the result of human error. Given the situation this is most likely true as it is fairly easy for an admin to accidentally change the wrong clients DNS settings if they just glance at the records.